# Is there any way of storing a command written in prompt into JSON file

Tags: c, json, linux

I am using ubuntu and i have used a library named as [ICLI](https://github.com/v3io/icli) (interactive command line interface) which lets one build his own prompt. and i want whatever command i write in this prompt to be stored as JSON.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. I assume you built something in Python - could you elaborate what you already tried and where you encountered problems?

Comment: No i have not used python...i have used a library(ICLI) written in c language. which helped me design a prompt. now i need to store the commands i use in this prompt as JSON in some file.

Comment: I have tried with jWrite thing...but it was not comforting....is there any way to convert log file into JSON?

Comment: While searching for icli I initially only found the Python one. I now linked and tagged the one for C but I think you'll need to describe your problem more closely.

Comment: Okay see,  with the help of icli i have my shell(Linux). Now suppose my shell gives >> as prompt for input in terminal. And as we know shell accepts input in form of commands. So, i will give some commands which i have defined in my shell. And i want these commands to be stored somewhere in file as json file.... And i have used only c programming till now.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing so is file write, for which you can try

```
with open("data_file.json", "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(data, write_file)
```

Here, `data` is a variable created before writing these lines. `data` contains whatever information needs to be stored, in JSON format.

Comment: Is there any way with C programming?,...and I need this to be dynamic like commands will be stored as JSON every time when I use.

Comment: And here...data variable has something as JSON structure only...which will be dumped into data_file.json right?  ...but in my case data is not structured as JSON. I think this just for readability of json file..??

Comment: And i want total dynamic thing ..like every time it will store my commands as JSON in some file.

Comment: @RajatSingh I still need to search for the dynamic thing, and will inform you as soon as I get it. And yes, this method is apt for data which is structured in JSON format.

Comment: Okay i will elaborate more, see with the help of icli i have my shell(Linux). Now suppose my shell gives >> as prompt for input in terminal. And as we know shell accepts input in form of commands. So, i will give some command which i have defined in my shell. And i want these commands to be stored somewhere in file as json file.... And i have used only c programming till now.

Comment: @RajatSingh gets more clear now. I'll try to get back to you soon with a solution